# No acces to front page but acces to backend is working

Tags: joomla-3.x, front-end, bugs

My Joomla 3.3.1 website was working fine until today. I haven't install nor updated anything since two-three weeks. Yesterday it was working great, but today I get this error message:

> This webpage is not available

I can still access my backend and it seems that all the pages are working except the one to create new article (no matter if I try directly from the menu or from the article manager page). But I can access any existing articles.

The weird thing is that I everything is working fine if I activate the Joomla Debug system : in that case, my front-end is working and I can create a new article.

I couldn't find any clue in the Joomla debug system.

Any idea what may be the origin and what I am supposed to do to fix ? Thanks a lot for your help!

What I have tried so far but it didn't solve the problem:

1. disable `Search Engine Friendly URLs` and `Use URL rewriting`.
2. remove redirection in `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure what happened but updating to Joomla 3.3.3 solve it:
I could reproduce under J3.3.3, the same error I had under J3.3.1 by modifying the module chrome file (\templates\mytemplate\html\module.php).

I haven't edited this file since a least a full month before the issue happened so I can't find out what was wrong.

Anyway, it's back now!

Update:
Actually updating to 3.3.2 didn't solve it, but it helped me to find a way to go around the bug. For still unknown reason, if I have a modules.php in mytemplate/html, then some pages on my website are unavailable. 
I went around by adding my chrome directly in templates\system\html\modules.php. Not the best method but  at least my website is back and with a nice module chrome!

Answer (score 1):

It works for me when I access the site, but it shows a lot of "Strict Standard" warnings. Mainly coming from a "DisplayNews" Module and from a layout override in "/templates/protostar/html/layouts/joomla/content/tags.php".
You may want to try disabling at least the module to see if it causes other issues as well as it doesn't look like it's written very well.

You should also disable debug informations for public as it will show all sort of sensible information to the visitors.

If the site is back in a state where it doesn't work, you should check the server error logfile and see if there are any errors logged there.

And of course check if the site isn't hacked. If you really didn't change anything and your host didn't change anything as well, then that may be the root of your issue.
There is a checklist in the doc pages which may help you: http://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced

Comment: Thanks for having had a look. Yes the front end is accessible when the debug is on but if I turn it off, then I have a "website not accessible" page (cf print screen in my question).

Comment: Ok I could get a bit more understanding of the issue. My home menu is a single article menu item and I change the article linked to the home menu and now I have access to my website with the debu set to off. Now the problem is that some menu items work well but other redirect me to the "website not available" page (cf print screen). Could it be that there is a bug somewhere in my Db rather than my website being hacked?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is working for me. It directs me to *yoururl.org/en/*

It therefore looks very much like you have a problem with the language settings, or indeed a extension which is having an issue with languages. Clearing your cookies may result in you being directed to the right language version, but the source of the problem will need to be determined by disabling each extension and seeing if it has any effect.

Comment: I actually have a bilingual website so the redirection to /en/ is normal. I will try as you said to disable all extension one by one.